Flutter: Trying to achieve Infinite scroll with Flutter
Here's my function:
  _onScroll() async {
if (_postScrollController.offset >=
        _postScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - 1000 &&
    !_postScrollController.position.outOfRange) {

       *Function to get next set of data*

    }

The problem that I'm facing with this function is whenever you scroll too quickly, it will sometimes load and call the function multiple times.
If I remove the - 1000 from the function, it works well but leaves you stuck for a few seconds at the bottom of the page waiting for the next set of data to load before you can keep scrolling, it's simply not very user friendly.
Is there any way of achieving infinite scroll in Flutter without using a dependency?
Thank you!

Try this
scrollController!.addListener(() async {
  if (scrollController!.position.maxScrollExtent ==
      scrollController!.position.pixels) {
   *Function to get next set of data*
  } 
});


If you wrap your master list in a riverpod provider, it doesn't matter how quickly ref.invalidate is called... it'll only ever rebuild once per frame, and then it has the cache of the new data.
